Theoretical explanation on calculating magnetic moment of materials in quantum mechanics
Could someone please provide a comprehensive and in detail theoretical explanation of how to calculates the magnetic moment of a material(total magnetic moment and absolute magnetic moment) of a material step by step in quantum mechanics from solving the schrodinger equation?.
Same question posted on matter modelling site - https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/13217/9983

Probably better suited for Matter Modeling SE.

@TobiasFünke I have already posted this question there, but I haven't received a reply yet.

Please link the question here (and link this question there). We have rules about cross-posting. In general, it is discouraged, though.

@TobiasFünke I will include the link in the body of the question is that okay

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Doesn't QE already compute it for you? If you read the documentation, there should be a place where you can switch on the magnetic moment computation. There are various levels of approximation, starting from the most rudimentary, fixed spin-up-down filling differences, to treating Dirac equation properly, etc.
